# Creating days from date in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying do find days from date and create new column for days.
I wrote this code:

```
for d in df['Date']:
df['Day'].append(days[calendar.weekday(int(d.strftime('%Y')),int(d.strftime('%m')),int(d.strftime('%d')))])
```

But this gives an error:

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ""; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Comment: what's your date format ? probably a small snippet would help

Comment: Can you give example of your data and desired output?

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Day'] = [int(i.day) for i in pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

if `df['A']` is your first date and `df['B']` is your second date you can create a new column that displays the difference in dates:

`df['C'] = df['A'] - df['B']`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

```
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.weekday_name
```

Comment: only if `df['Date']` is of `datetimelike`  type already, otherwise you will need to firstly consider if it s a string column. if it is, you will convert it using `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`